# How to include jsfiddle (or equivalent) in github markdown?

Tags: html, github, markdown, embed, jsfiddle

I'm looking for a way to embed some *html* in my .md *markdown* files.
Actually, I would like to embed *jsfiddle* resource in my markdown.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

It looks like current markdown specs does not provide a way to embed external html, even in github flavored markdown.

I have found the following project, from 2012, which is all about this, but I think it's only a kind of improvement proposal.

[Extending Markdown/MarkdownSharp for jsFiddle embedding](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/507944/extendingplusmarkdown-fmarkdownsharpplusforplusjs)

Note that the previous article references similar discussions but targeting **SO** instead of **GitHub** ( [Custom jsFiddle for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stack-overflow), [Auto-embed jsFiddle into questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141674/auto-embed-jsfiddle-into-questions) )

I checked the following references from GitHub without finding what I'm looking for ( [Mastering Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/), [Writing on GitHub](https://help.github.com/categories/writing-on-github/) )

Is the feature voluntarily not supported in GitHub markdown, would it be in a near future ?

Answer (score 3):

JSFiddle fiddles can be [embedded using an `<iframe>`](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/embedding-fiddles), and Markdown has always [supported embedded HTML](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html).

However for [security reasons](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/245) it is common for only a subset of HTML to be permitted. GitHub's [whitelist doesn't include the `<iframe>` tag](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/419436767dce642a03fa719cc1c75e23d174861b/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L44). I'm not aware of any way to do what you want that is compatible with GitHub's tag whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't. I tried using the `<iframe>` and the `<script>` tag in Markdown and it simply doesn't work.